# Pyinstaller importing too many modules

Tags: python

I have this modules imported:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import mechanicalsoup
```

When i run pyinstaller with this command:

```
pyinstaller Final.py --onefile
```

A whole bunch of modules get imported, like Matplotlib, Pyqt - i think the entire installed module bunch and the executable Final.exe has 200mb.

Any ideas why and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution- Just use a virtual environment with the option `--no-site-packages`, install the modules you need and that's all.